# Joined table attributes in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a loop within a loop to render some data in a view and am having some troubles.

I have two models: User and Task.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Associations
    has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Associations
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Hence, the Task model has a column called "user_id".

My goal is to render in a view the following:

- User.first_name (#1)
- Task 1
- Task 2
- User.first_name (#2)
- Task 1
- Task 2

So my view looks like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 task-header">
    <strong><%= user.first_name %></strong>
  </div>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <%= task.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to print the name of each User and associate all of their tasks with that specific user.

The controller:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @tasks = User.joins(:tasks).where(tasks: {user_id: 1})
  end
```

This is where I am getting confused. I know I probably need to join the tables together, but in the view, once the tables are joined, I can't pull any of the columns from the tasks table (or at least I don't know how to).

Further, I am explicitly stating a user_id = 1. That is not dynamic, so that won't work. How do I dynamically grab the user_id from the first part of my loop?

Hopefully you understand my task at hand :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will print your users along with their tasks in the format you want.

**Controller**

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

**View**

```
<% @users.to_enum.with_index(1).each do do |user, index| %>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 task-header">
    <strong><%= "#{user.first_name} (##{index})" %></strong>
  </div>
  <% user.tasks.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |task, i| %>
    <div><%= "#{task.title} {i}" %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Using the `with_index` allows you to specify the index within the enumeration.  Also, as you've said you want tasks for the particular user in each loop, you don't need to define `@tasks` in your controller action.  Since their association is defined appropriately you could just do `user.tasks` in your view.

Comment: Man, I hope I get to this level of understanding sooner than later :) - thanks!!

Comment: Last question here: How do I then go about limiting the number of tasks returned under each user to say 5?

Comment: @meebix, you could add a `limit` as follows: `user.tasks.limit(5).to_enum.with_index(1).each`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'll want to use `includes` in your controller in order to do only one query instead of n+1 for each user...

Controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.includes(:tasks).all
end
```

Then in your view, because you have an association set up on `User` where each `User` `has_many :tasks`, you can do:

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 task-header">
    <strong><%= user.first_name %></strong>
  </div>
  <% user.tasks.each |task| %>
    <%= task.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you *literally* want the numbers next to each item, use `each_with_index` on each iterator:

```
<% @users.each_with_index do |user, index| %>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 task-header">
    <strong><%= user.first_name %>(#<%= index %>)</strong>
  </div>
  <% user.tasks.each_with_index |task, index| %>
    <%= task.title %>(#<%= index %>)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Only gave it to the above because he answered first. This works too! Really appreciate the response

Comment: Ha!  Fair enough.  :)

Comment: Though, you should consider using the `includes` - your DB will thank you as you get more users. ;-)

Comment: Good to know - appreciate it!